# Create Distinct Column Values as Extra Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any tricks anyone can share on how to manipulate the following table

```
ID TYPE Name Description
1  X    A    DESC_A
2  X    B    DESC_B
3  Z    C    DESC_C
```

to this view?

```
NAME_X DESCRIPTION_X
A      DESC_A
B      DESC_B
NAME_Z DESCRIPTION_Z
C      DESC_C
```

For every distinct column, I would like to create a custom row for every distinct value in the 'TYPE' column. In this example, the custom row is created by appending the TYPE value to 'NAME_' and 'DESCRIPTION_'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Return some meta data from the view:

```
alter view dbo.yourView
as
with c_Distinct([type])
as  (   select  distinct [Type]
        from    dbo.yourTable   
    )
select  [Sort] = 0,
        [Type],
        Name, 
        [Description] 
from    dbo.yourTable
union all
select  [Sort] = 1,
        [Type],
        'NAME_'+[Type],
        'DESCRIPTION_'+[Type]
from    c_Distinct
```

And then perform the ordering when selecting from the View:

```
select *
from yourView
order by [Type] asc, [Sort] desc
```

Comment: This produces the same result as the answer above too but does not sort them too. Thanks!

Comment: Do the ordering when selecting from the view

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create view vwTestDistinctData
as
    select [type], [Description]
    from testdistinctdata
    union all
    select 
        'NAME_' + [type] as [Type],
        'DESCRIPTION_' + [type] as [Description]
    from testdistinctdata
    group by [type]
go
```

Comment: This produces the correct result set but it does not order/group the custom row correctly. Any more ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @MackPro You probably know that it's not possible to put an Order By clause in a view? Is there a reason why putting the Order By in your Select would not be acceptable?

Comment: I needed extra columns to sort the records in a certain way and a simple order by wouldn't work. I hate mental block. Thanks for everyone's input!